# Openstack Horizon Service Fail due -- "openstack-dashboard: 500" --packstack installation on Centos7

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

I tried several times to install Openstack via Packstack on my Centos 7 ( Linux 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64) VM. The problem is that Horizon Service is not working. If I check via "openstack-status" than I can see this error:

[root@server1 httpd]# openstack-status
== Keystone service ==
openstack-keystone:                     inactive  (disabled on boot)
== Horizon service ==
**openstack-dashboard:                    500**

Here is the output of horizon_error.log

> [Fri Sep 22 10:34:27.281917 2017] [:error] [pid 29584] WARNING:root:"dashboards" and "default_dashboard" in (local_)settings is DEPRECATED now and may be unsupported in some future release. The preferred way to specify the order of dashboards and the default dashboard is the pluggable dashboard mechanism (in /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/enabled, /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/local/enabled).
> [Fri Sep 22 10:35:41.865062 2017] [:error] [pid 29586] WARNING:root:"dashboards" and "default_dashboard" in (local_)settings is DEPRECATED now and may be unsupported in some future release. The preferred way to specify the order of dashboards and the default dashboard is the pluggable dashboard mechanism (in /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/enabled, /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/local/enabled).
> [Fri Sep 22 10:39:31.927589 2017] [core:error] [pid 29611] [client ::1:50612] End of script output before headers: django.wsgi
> [Fri Sep 22 10:40:48.146592 2017] [core:error] [pid 29632] [client ::1:50682] End of script output before headers: django.wsgi
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:48.754993 2017] [:error] [pid 110191] WARNING:root:"dashboards" and "default_dashboard" in (local_)settings is DEPRECATED now and may be unsupported in some future release. The preferred way to specify the order of dashboards and the default dashboard is the pluggable dashboard mechanism (in /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/enabled, /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/local/enabled).
> [Fri Sep 22 10:55:53.987761 2017] [core:error] [pid 110223] [client ::1:51630] End of script output before headers: django.wsgi
> [Fri Sep 22 11:04:00.792056 2017] [:error] [pid 111616] WARNING:root:"dashboards" and "default_dashboard" in (local_)settings is DEPRECATED now and may be unsupported in some future release. The preferred way to specify the order of dashboards and the default dashboard is the pluggable dashboard mechanism (in /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/enabled, /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/local/enabled).
> [Fri Sep 22 11:09:05.859637 2017] [core:error] [pid 111625] [client ::1:52294] End of script output before headers: django.wsg>

and error.log

> [Fri Sep 22 10:49:49.691043 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29575] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.431096 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 110182] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442501 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module access_compat_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442516 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module actions_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442528 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module alias_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442613 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module auth_basic_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442620 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module auth_digest_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442624 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module authn_anon_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442646 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module authn_core_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442738 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module authn_dbm_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442744 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module authn_file_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442832 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module authz_core_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442912 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module authz_dbm_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442920 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module authz_groupfile_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442924 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module authz_host_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442927 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module authz_owner_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442931 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module authz_user_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442935 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module autoindex_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.442939 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module cache_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.443172 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module deflate_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.443178 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module dir_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.443321 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module env_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.443328 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module expires_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.443333 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module ext_filter_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.443337 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module filter_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.443423 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module include_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.443518 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module log_config_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.443525 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module logio_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.443530 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module mime_magic_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.443534 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module mime_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.443538 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module negotiation_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.443685 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.443720 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module setenvif_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.444194 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module substitute_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.444205 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module suexec_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.444291 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module unixd_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.444377 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module version_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.444385 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module vhost_alias_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.444402 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module dav_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.444412 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module dav_fs_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.445171 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module mpm_prefork_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.447082 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module systemd_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.447130 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module cgi_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.447142 2017] [so:warn] [pid 110182] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.451773 2017] [alias:warn] [pid 110182] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.conf at line 21 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.452539 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 110182] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.556372 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 110182] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.866065 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 110182] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
> [Fri Sep 22 10:50:16.866112 2017] [core:notice] [pid 110182] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
> [Fri Sep 22 11:02:12.621022 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 110182] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.278069 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 111604] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327078 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module access_compat_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327093 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module actions_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327099 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module alias_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327174 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module auth_basic_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327181 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module auth_digest_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327185 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module authn_anon_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327189 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module authn_core_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327271 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module authn_dbm_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327277 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module authn_file_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327360 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module authz_core_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327452 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module authz_dbm_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327459 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module authz_groupfile_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327464 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module authz_host_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327467 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module authz_owner_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327471 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module authz_user_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327475 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module autoindex_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327479 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module cache_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327740 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module deflate_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327747 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module dir_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327927 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module env_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327937 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module expires_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327947 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module ext_filter_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.327952 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module filter_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.328046 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module include_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.328181 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module log_config_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.328188 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module logio_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.328193 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module mime_magic_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.328197 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module mime_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.328202 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module negotiation_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.328357 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.328369 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module setenvif_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.328850 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module substitute_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.328861 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module suexec_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.328959 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module unixd_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.329044 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module version_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.329051 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module vhost_alias_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.329070 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module dav_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.329075 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module dav_fs_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.329754 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module mpm_prefork_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.331569 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module systemd_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.331650 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module cgi_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.331669 2017] [so:warn] [pid 111604] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.346650 2017] [alias:warn] [pid 111604] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.conf at line 21 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.347663 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 111604] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.464545 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 111604] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.563230 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 111604] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
> [Fri Sep 22 11:03:01.563299 2017] [core:notice] [pid 111604] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
> [root@server1 httpd]#

Can somebody help me to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Got it! This solved the issue!

https://bugs.launchpad.net/horizon/+bug/1573488/comments/6